# Thread terminated although joined and always in scope

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to write a program that computes the scalar product of two vectors in parallel. For this, I'm using a binary tree structure of threads: initially, each thread computes the scalar product of a specific range in the two vectors, then each thread waits for its two children to finish before terminating itself (for thread with id `n`, the two children are threads with id `2 * n + 1` and `2 * n + 2`). In the end, I'll just wait for thread with id `0` (the root of the binary tree) to terminate and I should have the final result.

However, this approach fails to work as I'm getting a strange `terminate called without an active exception` error right after the creation of the first thread (thread with id `numThreads - 1`).

I've read that this happens whenever a thread goes out of scope and it was not joined. I consider that this is not the case here, no thread goes out of scope and, in the end, I'm waiting for thread `0` which, indirectly, joins all the other existing threads.

Here is the full source code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

int leftNode(int index) { return 2 * index + 1; }
int rightNode(int index) { return 2 * index + 2; }

bool hasLeftNode(int numThreads, int index) {
  int node = leftNode(index);
  return node >= 0 && node < numThreads;
}
bool hasRightNode(int numThreads, int index) {
  int node = rightNode(index);
  return node >= 0 && node < numThreads;
}

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> splitWorkload(int n, int numThreads) {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> intervals;

  int index = 0;
  int step = n / numThreads;
  int mod = n % numThreads;

  while (index < n) {
    intervals.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(index, index + step + (mod > 0)));
    index += step + (mod > 0);
    mod--;
  }

  return intervals;
}

int scalarProduct(std::vector<int> &a, std::vector<int> &b, int n, int numThreads) {
  std::vector<int> sums(n, 0);

  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  threads.reserve(numThreads);

  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> intervals = splitWorkload(n, numThreads); 
  for (int i = numThreads - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    threads[i] = std::thread([&, i]() {
      for (int k = intervals[i].first; k < intervals[i].second; k++) {
        sums[i] += a[k] * b[k];
      }

      if (hasLeftNode(numThreads, i)) {
        threads[leftNode(i)].join();
        sums[i] += sums[leftNode(i)];
      }

      if (hasRightNode(numThreads, i)) {
        threads[rightNode(i)].join();
        sums[i] += sums[rightNode(i)];
      }
    });
  }

  threads[0].join();
  return sums[0];
}

int main() {
  int n = 10000;

  std::vector<int> a;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a.push_back(i);
  }

  std::vector<int> b;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    b.push_back(i + 1);
  }

  int numThreads = 4;
  std::cout << scalarProduct(a, b, n, numThreads) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are joining only the first thread. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Yes, in the main thread, but the first thread joins its children, which in turn join their children, and so on.

Comment: If you step through your code statement by statement in a debugger (while monitoring variables and their values) does everything behave as expected? Do all function return what they're supposed to return? You're not going out of bounds of any array or vector?

Comment: `std::vector<std::thread> threads;` `threads[0].join();` this doesn't look like properly joining threads. Also you never sized `threads`, so your using accessing it out of bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) does not create the vector elements. Use [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) instead:

```
threads.reserve(numThreads);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the point that has mentioned correctly by @vll, for large values of `n`, the sum will be really big and cannot be kept inside an `int` variable. So, it is better to store them inside a `long long` variable:

```
long long scalarProduct(std::vector<int> &a, std::vector<int> &b, int n, int numThreads) 
{
   std::vector<long long> sums(n, 0);

   // rest of the code
```